# JProfiler: how do I populate query param in JDBC view?

Tags: jprofiler

As per the title.
The article [here](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/index.html) doesnt help.
Tried to go Session->Session Setting->Database Settings->JDBC, tick all available tick boxes, but I still get unpopulated query in my JDBC events view.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query parameters are appended at the end of the SQL statement in square brackets in a map-like syntax, you can see that in your screenshot: [1: ..., 2: ..., 3:...].